# Explanation about pandas value_counts function

Tags: python, pandas

Can someone please explain what does the line

```
result = data.apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0)
```

does in here?

```
import pandas as pd 
from pandas import Series, DataFrame

data = DataFrame({'Qu1': [1, 3, 4, 3, 4],
                  'Qu2': [2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
                  'Qu3': [1, 5, 2, 4, 4]})

result = data.apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0)  

In [26]:data
Out[26]:
Qu1 Qu2 Qu3
0 1 2 1
1 3 3 5
2 4 1 2
3 3 2 4
4 4 3 4

In [27]:result
Out[28]:
Qu1 Qu2 Qu3
1 1 1 1
2 0 2 1
3 2 2 0
4 2 0 2
5 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs, it produces a histogram of non-null values. Looking just at column `Qu1` of `result`, we can tell that there is one 1, zero 2's, two 3's, two 4's, and zero 5's in the original column `data.Qu1`.

Comment: Thank you. I was not familiar with the term histogram, otherwise it is very clear. Too bad the example values does not help.

Answer (score 8):

I think the easiest way to understand what's going on is to break it down.

One each column, value_counts simply counts the number of occurrences of each value in the Series (i.e. in 4 appears twice in the Qu1 column):

```
In [11]: pd.value_counts(data.Qu1)
Out[11]:
4    2
3    2
1    1
dtype: int64
```

When you do an apply each column is realigned with the other results, since every value between 1 and 5 is seen it's aligned with `range(1, 6)`:

```
In [12]: pd.value_counts(data.Qu1).reindex(range(1, 6))
Out[12]:
1     1
2   NaN
3     2
4     2
5   NaN
dtype: float64
```

You want to count the values you didn't see as 0 rather than NaN, hence the fillna:

```
In [13]: pd.value_counts(data.Qu1).reindex(range(1, 6)).fillna(0)
Out[13]:
1    1
2    0
3    2
4    2
5    0
dtype: float64
```

When you do the apply, it concats the result of doing this for each column:

```
In [14]: pd.concat((pd.value_counts(data[col]).reindex(range(1, 6)).fillna(0)
                       for col in data.columns),
                   axis=1, keys=data.columns)
Out[14]:
   Qu1  Qu2  Qu3
1    1    1    1
2    0    2    1
3    2    2    0
4    2    0    2
5    0    0    1
```